# How do I get Keywords to show up in a vue website?

Tags: seo, keyword-stuffing

I'm trying to make my website more friendly for search engines and I have been running it through ubbersuggest to monitor the site's organic keywords always appear as nothing, which doesn't make sense to me because I have the metadata on the page shown below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/icon.png" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/icon.png" />
    <title>Title | Website Name</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Webpage description." />
    <meta name="google-site-verification" content="code" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="Keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3, Keyword4">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I know that meta keywords aren't used anymore but I thought I would put it in just to cover all bases, I've also tried putting `H1`, `H2`, `H3` and `p` elements with the keywords in them as well as putting `div- title = 'Keyword'` and `<a id='Keyword`'.

I've tried all these things and still nothing not one keyword registers when I recrawl the website and I can't figure out why there should be at least something if anyone has any ideas or help it would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: What are you using to crawl your website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are whole businesses out there dedicated to tuning this for you and organisations fork out thousands of dollars.  Because it is not an easy or definitive process.

Google, at least, makes its own keywords based on your url, content, tags etc.  Even the description tag is a suggestion.

That said, you can achieve some success, use one of the many websites out there that help you in this.  Note that if your website is relatively new, then Google may not index your website fully for a while, maybe as long as a year.